# How do I delete an interaction command reply in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

my bot is replying for every slash command. I think it is because of commandInteraction. I tried interaction.deleteReply but didn't work. How can i stop replying from slash command?

this is what my codes are looks like

```
async execute(client, interaction, args, ee) {
    try {

        const guildData = await rrModel.findOne({
            guildId: interaction.guildId
        });

        if (!guildData?.roles) return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${client.allEmojis.x} MenuRole System`)
                .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
                .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)
                .setDescription(`**There is no MenuRole Exist**`)
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please specify discord.js version, full code and the exact error please. Next, whether you use a command handler or not, you don't reply to a slash command unless you actually add a line containing something like
`interaction.reply("Whatever you want")`, and even then it only replies to every interaction if you don't put it in an if condition.

Now, for the piece of code I see, you reply whenever `guildData?.roles` returns false. This means that either, you aren't getting the roles correct, or it just never return true since there is no `guildData.roles`

Comment: discord.js version is (v13.6.0) and there is no error. mainly when i use slash command by bot respond by replaying my command. so i just want to stop interaction reply.

Comment: @MahdiHasan the only thing I see with your code, is that it replies because of guildData.roles, and as long as that is not true, it will continue responding. If it is something else, please console.log guildData.roles and send me the full code.